# php - load two pages one after another

Tags: php

i have one page with a navbar button on top. Also, i use one sonoff wifi switch to power on/off one lamp.

I am trying to make this task order to work.

1. User press on navbar the button.
2. Load power_off.php, which is the code below.
3. After 2seconds redirect to google page.

Code power_off.php

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['valid']);
unset($_SESSION['timeout']);

header( "url=http://192.168.2.2/cs?cmnd=Power%20Off" );
header( "refresh:2;url=http://www.google.gr/" );
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please update your question and provide a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with relevant code parts. i.e. HTML 
Click here for tips on how to ask good questions that are likely to be well-received by the community and attract good answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution modifying the Power Off script:**

In your entry script:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['valid']);
unset($_SESSION['timeout']);

header( "Location: http://192.168.2.2/cs?cmnd=Power%20Off" );
?>
```

then at the end of that file, the one that makes the poweroff you add

```
sleep(2); //if you want to wait 2 seconds... 
header( "Location: http://www.google.gr/" );
exit;
```

**Solution with CURL:**

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['valid']);
unset($_SESSION['timeout']);

//Initialize cURL.
$ch = curl_init("http://192.168.2.2/cs?cmnd=Power%20Off"); 
//Execute the request.
curl_exec($ch); 
//Close the cURL handle.
curl_close($ch);

sleep(2); //wait for 2 seconds. Remove if not needed.
header( "Location: https://www.google.com" ); //redirect to Google
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your message. Can you explain pls the first solution as i don't know much from curl. All my code is on php file. First part, end session. Second part, load sonoff switch url. Third part, redirect to google page.

Comment: Thank you. I now got it. I must also, add to sonoff firmware the extra lines using Terminal and PY. I will test also the curl solution. It is very good explain.

Comment: I prefer the CURL solution as it does not requires to modify the other script. There are ways to obtain the result of the CURL call, so you can use conditionals according to this. If success go to Google, else error page, for example